# Protégé reasoner does not infer subclass

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, description-logic, dlquery

I have a small ontology defined as shown in the following picture:

[image]

I created an individual for `Dataset` and one for `Algorithm`. I expected that the `reasoner` would infer the `Algorithm` individual as `Linear_Least_Regression`, but this didn't happen.

This is the definition of the `Dataset` individual. As it can be seen, the individual fulfils the requirements for a `Dataset` needed by the `Linear_Least_Regression`
[image]

Also, if I add the `Linear_Least_Regression` as a type for the `Algorithm` individual, the reasoner does not complain.

I also tried to get the `Linear_Least_Regression` as a result with a `DL Query` but this also didn't work.

[image]

Did I miss something when modelling my ontology or does the problem lie at the reasoner?
I tried following two reasoners: `FaCT++ 1.6.5` and `HermiT 1.3.8.413` and `Protégé 5`

Comment: OWL makes OWA — open world assumption. Try to make properties functional (if that meets your requirements). Please do not paste images instead of code.

Comment: @StanislavKralin making the properties functional did not help. O posted pictures, because in my opinion, it easier to determine the structure from the pictures than from the owl

Comment: You defined `LinearRegression` as subclass of `hasDataset only (hasObservations >= 250)` You're querying for `hasDataset only (hasObservations value 280)` but why do you expect that `LinearRegression` should be returned? As a superclass or what do you expect?

Comment: @AKSW I expected to see `Linear_Least_Regression` returned as `Subclasses`/`Direct Subclasses`, but that didn't happen.

Comment: Hm, `Linear_Least_Regression` is just a **subclass of** something that is more general than `hasDataset only (hasObservations value 280)`, or not? I mean, an instance could also have a dataset with only 251 observation, I don't get why any `Linear_Least_Regression` should be an instance of `hasDataset only (hasObservations value 280)`, i.e. which always has a dataset with exactly 280 observations.

Comment: the `Linear_Least_regression` is a subclass of `hasDataset only (hasObservations  only xsd:integer[>= 250]` and in the query I want to receive the class which fulfills `hasDataset only (hasObservations value 280)`. I think that I'm pretty clear in in the defined axioms.

Comment: if it helps, I can post the `owl` file

Comment: No, I don't think so. OWL semantics is based on set theory. Please think about both class definitions as sets of instances. And then think about which one comprises more instances. It should be clear that `hasDataset only (hasObservations value 280)` is more general than `hasDataset only (hasObservations value 280)`

Comment: @AKSW what do you mean by "more general"?

Comment: I mixed up the definitions, first one should be the one from the `Linear_Least_regression` subclass axiom, i.e. `hasDataset only (hasObservations only xsd:integer[>= 250])`. This one is obviously more general, isn't it? I mean, it covers more instances than the class of `hasDataset only (hasObservations value 280)` - *"everything that has only datasets with more than 250 observations"* is broader than *"everything that has only datasets with exactly 280 observations"* isn't it?

Comment: yes, but shouldn't the case `hasDataset only (hasObservations value 280)` fall into `hasDataset only (hasObservations only xsd:integer[>= 250]`? I'm thinking now, that maybe I should add some restrictions on the classes.

Comment: because I declared `Algorithm hasDataset only Dataset` and due to `OWA`, it can be that the reasoner decides that `Algorithm` is the correct type for the created individual, although it could also fit `Linear_Least_Regression`

Comment: `hasDataset only (hasObservations value 280)` falls into `hasDataset only (hasObservations only xsd:integer[>= 250])`, yes. But this means, it's a subclass of it, not a superclass. Let's make it more abstract, and rewrite `Linear_Least_regression`, `hasDataset only (hasObservations only xsd:integer[>= 250])` and `hasDataset only (hasObservations value 280)` with `A`, `B` and `C` respectively. So, we have `A SubClassOf B` and we also know that `C SubClassOf B`, right? What you can see now is that there is no chain from `A` to `C` because it's only `A SubClassOf B` and not `A EquivalentTo B`

Comment: @AKSW this makes sense. Thank you for your explanation. I moved now hasDataset only (hasObservations only xsd:integer[>= 250] from subClass of to equivalent to and the DL query works perfectly.